# How to move ionic video capture to file_put_contents() in php

Tags: php, ionic3

we created an ionic app which captures video  but we are facing challenges saving this video to a directory in on the server. I have searched online for this but couldn't find a tutorial about it.

On the code below, the video name was saved in the videos folder instead of the actual video

//Upload video php part

```
 $postjson = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

 if(!empty($postjson['video'])){
            $video = $postjson['video'];
            $now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
            $id = $now -> format('YmdHisu');
            $upload_folder = "videos";
            $path ="$upload_folder/$id.mp4";
            
            $actualpath = "http://url/incident/api/$path";
            file_put_contents($path,$video);
            
        
            }
```

On the ionic part, I have this:

```
captureVideo() {
    let options: CaptureVideoOptions = {
      limit: 1,
      duration: 120
    }
    this.mediaCapture.captureVideo(options).then((res: MediaFile[]) => {
      let capturedFile = res[0];
      let fileName = capturedFile.name;
      let dir = capturedFile['localURL'].split('/');
      dir.pop();
      let fromDirectory = dir.join('/');
      var toDirectory = this.file.dataDirectory;
      this.ivideo = fileName;
      this.viddir = dir;
      console.log("video captured "+this.ivideo);
    
      this.file.copyFile(fromDirectory , fileName , toDirectory , fileName).then((res) => {
        this.storeMediaFiles([{name: fileName, size: capturedFile.size}]);
      },err => {
        console.log('err: ', err);
      });
          },
    (err: CaptureError) => console.error(err));
  }
```

Sending to the server using post method in code summary:

```
 var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    //headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST' );
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    
   
     let data = {
           aksi : 'insert_incident',
           title: this.title.value,
           descr: this.descr.value,
           images : this.cameraData,
           video: this.ivideo,
         };

   this.http.post(this.global.serverAddress+"api/getCategories.php", data, options)
   .map(res => res.json())
   .subscribe(res => {
   
    loader.dismiss()
   if(res=="Done"){
     let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
       title:"Done",
       subTitle: "Sent",
       buttons: ['OK']
       });
      
       alert.present();
   }else
   {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title:"ERROR",
    subTitle:(res),
    buttons: ['OK']
    });
   
    alert.present();
     } 
   }
```

Comment: So, file is not being saved or you are unable to play video on the server?

Comment: @nice_dev, the name was saved but could play it.

Comment: Then, something to do with sending of binary data. Are you able to see correct data format being sent in network tab?

Comment: Why use input stream? Does, POST and $_FILE not work good?

Comment: @nice_dev, yes, in .mp4

Comment: $_POST and f$_FILE didn't work. I tried it before but it gave error.

Comment: Ok, what error? Have you tried this method in [`this docs`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer) ?

Comment: @nice_dev, I have PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title